# Querying a fusion table to see if a polygon contains a coordinate

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, polygons, point-in-polygon

Is there a way to determine if a coordinate is inside a fusion table layer?  I tried to do this with a few homegrown methods but around 6% of the locations I’m testing are returning false results. One of the results says that Glasgow is not in Scotland.

Can I query [this Fusion Table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1d5LmqKYvkTDxmYK3-9-aQLNz3Z0QAEwqHusAm5w) and ask it if Glasgow is in Scotland? Preferably returning a boolean value.

1. Glasgow coords: `55.855513, -4.252649`
2. Scotland query: `Geometry where ‘NAME’ = ‘Scotland’`
3. KML column: `Geometry`
4. Fusion Table Id: `1d5LmqKYvkTDxmYK3-9-aQLNz3Z0QAEwqHusAm5w`

I think I have to use `ST_CONTAINS` or `ST_INTERSECTS` but I'm not sure how, if they work with polygon shapes.

**Overall Solution**

Using the query in the given answer you can get the name of the polygon using the FusionTablesAPI.

```
lat = 55.855513
lng = -4.252649
table = '1d5LmqKYvkTDxmYK3-9-aQLNz3Z0QAEwqHusAm5w'
query = "SELECT NAME FROM #{table} WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(#{lat}, #{lng}),1))"
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=#{URI.encode(query)}&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ"
```

[Here is the output.](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20NAME%20FROM%201d5LmqKYvkTDxmYK3-9-aQLNz3Z0QAEwqHusAm5w%20WHERE%20ST_INTERSECTS%28geometry,%20CIRCLE%28LATLNG%2855.855513,%20-4.252649%29,1%29%29&key=AIzaSyAm9yWCV7JPCTHCJut8whOjARd7pwROFDQ)

This is actually a better solution than I set out to find.

Using the code in the the given answer highlights the polygon on a map which is awesome. Also, `postgres` can be used too as suggested by Dr.Molle in the comments.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't, currently in FusionTables `ST_INTERSECTS` only works with rectangles and circles

Comment: Hi Dr.Molle, thanks again! Do you know the best alternative way to do this? Without tweaking an algorithm. I'm thinking about using Execjs to compile Google Maps on the server and then run containsLocation(). But then I have to convert the KML to a polygon and the whole process just seems a little crazy. There must be a better way...

Comment: Sorry thats probably a separate question.. Thanks again for your help and help the other day too :)

Comment: I've seen that you've asked questions tagged with `postgres` , you may use a postgres-query with ST_CONTAINS(either based on data stored in a postgres-table or a polygon created on the fly )

Comment: Could I create a polygon on the fly with a fusion table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this (FusionTableLayer example):

```
        layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
          query: {
            select: 'geometry',
            from: tableId,
            where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(' + lat + ', ' + lng + '),1))',
            limit: 1
          }
```

Checks for the intersection of the polygon defined in the geometry column and a circle at lat,lng with a diameter of 1 meter.

[FusionTablesLayer exmaple](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTables_geocoder_PointInPolygon.html)

Comment: Can I get this to return a boolean? With this I could use containsLocation() I guess. What do you think?

Comment: Very helpful site by the way :).

Comment: Just to confirm, above is basically stating that the circle and the polygon are in the same place?

Comment: The ST_INTERSECTS is returning the polygons that intersect with a small circle.  If the polygon intersects with the circle, the circle is small enough and the polygons don't overlap, it will return the polygon that contains the input coordinates.  That specific example might be problematic if the coordinates are within 1 meter of the edge of two polygons.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get this code to return a boolean or the name of the polygon. It works well to visually see the region, but I'm going to be running automated processes to find if a point is inside a polygon. Do you know how to get it to do that? `containsLocation()` only works with polygons, not layers, unfortunately.

Comment: You need to use the [Fusion Tables API v1](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started) (or the google visualization API).  If it returns a result, your boolean would be true, if there are no results to the query your boolean is false.